# переадресация .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

как с помощью .htaccess переадресовывать пользователя с:

```
http://www.domainname.com// на http://www.domainname.com
http://www.domainname.com/// на http://www.domainname.com
http://www.domainname.com/index.html/ на http://www.domainname.com
http://www.domainname.com/sdfdsf/ на http://www.domainname.com
```

Comment: пробовали `mod_rewrite`?

Comment: да но никак не реагирует что то(

Comment: добавьте код, как вы пробовали это сделать.

Comment: плюс, убедитесь что файл `.htaccess` обрабатывается Апачем и подключен модуль mod_rewrite.

Comment: файл подключается и все ок, только непойму что задавать в mod_rewrite...это регулярку писать надо?

Comment: все....положил сервер теперь ничего не работает

Comment: ребят ну поможет кто то или как?

Comment: делаю так:
`
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule switcher.php - [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://siteadmin.loc/ [R=301,L]
`
http://siteadmin.loc/index.php/ но с этой не перенаправляет на корень сайта

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^OLDDOMAIN\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://NEWDOMAIN.com [R=301,L]
```